# Mosquitto MQTT Broker Dynamic Security Plugin not working in ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, dynamic, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to implement dynamic security plugin in mosquitto broker using the following documentation

https://mosquitto.org/documentation/dynamic-security/#installation

my **mosquitto.conf** file looks like this

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous false
per_listener_settings false

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

plugin /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mosquitto_dynamic_security.so
plugin_opt_config_file /var/lib/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
```

after making configuration changes if I start the mosquitto service it is failing to start and when I check **sudo journalctl -xu mosquitto** i can see and error

```
Mosquitto Error: Unknown configuration variable "plugin"
```

plugin is available in this path **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mosquitto_dynamic_security.so**
and it has 777 permission, am I missing something? because the same working in windows.

Comment: What version of Mosquitto are you using?

Comment: mosquitto version 1.6.10

mosquitto is an MQTT v3.1.1 broker.

Comment: OK `1.6.10` is a couple of years old (2020-05-25). I'm pretty sure the `plugin` option was added in version 2.0 (can't see it in the man page for [`1.6.15`](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/v1.6.15/man/mosquitto.conf.5.xml)).

Comment: good clue @Brits but i couldn't upgrade the version, when i purge the existing version and install using sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mosquitto-dev/mosquitto-ppa the old version is still remains in the server

Comment: The [download page](https://mosquitto.org/download/) has instructions for installing from a custom ppa.